# Read Excel cell value and de-serialize using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have an Excel sheet in which I have values which are similar to this:

```
<Element id="1" Name="Some Name" Value="4" Unit="Some UNit" />
```

Now from my C# code, I'm reading this Excel.

I have a class file in my application similar to

```
public class InputData{

  [DataMember(Name = "id")]
  public string id { get; set; }

  [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Value")]
  public string Value { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Unit")]
  public string Unit { get; set; }
}
```

I'm able to read the cell value using following code :

```
foreach (var worksheet in Workbook.Worksheets(@"C:\Test\Book1.xlsx"))
            {
                foreach (var row in worksheet.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (var cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(cell.Text);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I have followed [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/801032/Csharp-How-To-Read-xlsx-Excel-File-With-Lines-of) link to do so.
Now my requirement is to deserialize the cell value and form a list of InputData.

```
List<InputData> lst = new List<InputData>();

InputData inputData = new InputData;
inputData.id ="" ; //assign value
inputData.Name ="" ; //assign value
inputData.Value ="" ; //assign value
inputData.Unit ="" ; //assign value

lst.Add(inputData);
```

I want to add this in the loop, but I do not know how to deserialize this cell value as it is not exactly XML format. The only crude way I could think of is split based on spaces and access the values.

Is a better solution available?

### Note

I was not clear before, but I what I meant was each cell in my Excel has this similar type of data. I'm trying to loop through each cell and make a list.

**EDIT**

```
foreach (var row in worksheet.Rows)
{
     foreach (var cell in row.Cells)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(cell.Text);    

       Console.WriteLine(XDocument.Parse(cell.Text).Root.Attribute("id").Value);

          Console.ReadLine();
      }
}
```

In the first line , it prints this as mentioned above.

```
<Element id="1" Name="Some Name" Value="4" Unit="Some UNit" />
```

Comment: So are you getting `Id`, `Name`, `Value`, `Unit` in innermost foreach loop => `foreach (var cell in row.Cells)` ?

Comment: @er-sho yes, I'm doing this in innermost loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `XDocument.Parse`, for example:

```
inputData.id = XDocument.Parse(cell.Text).Root.Attribute("id").Value
```

Comment: This is giving exception - An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ConsoleApplication1.exe

Comment: can you post the complete code that gives exception? maybe in your innermost loop you encounter a cell without text?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the code which I'm using for testing. For now I have only one cell in my excel with value --> <Element id="1" Name="Some Name" Value="4" Unit="Some UNit" />